# Связи между вопросами

Tags: дефект, поддержка, комментарии

Почему после указания [в комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496938/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-deprecated-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b#comment589407_496938) ссылки на другой вопрос, они не стали связанными?

Answer (score 4):

Возможно, дело в сокращённой ссылке. Запостил полную ссылку `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454323/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C`
И связь образовалась.