# Невозможное [функциональное-программирование]

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, создание-метки

В последнее время было задано несколько вопросов, связанных с функциональным программированием, к которым стоило бы добавить метку [функциональное-программирование], но такую метку невозможно создать, потому что срабатывает ограничение на длину метки (30 символов):

> [image: попытка добавить метку]

На en.SO есть метка [functional-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming), в принципе можно создать такую же на ru.SO, но все-таки хотелось бы видеть локализованный вариант метки, но тогда нужно будет увеличить максимальную длину метки.

Данную метку можно было бы использовать для вопросов по теории функционального программирования без привязки к конкретным языкам, либо как дополнение к другим меткам (к примеру для вопросов об использовании функционального стиля в мультипарадигменных языках).

Comment: О, снова в длину не уложились... Один раз уже увеличивали.

Comment: [tag:функциональщина]

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну эт не серьезно. Лучше уж английский вариант.

Comment: @insolor шучу же )

Comment: И ведь всего-то не хватило одного символ

Comment: Кажется, я знаю, почему не запустили Stack Overflow auf Deutsch.

Comment: Предложение лосю проверить ошибки - тоже ничего...

Comment: Любопытно, что на Мете уже [25 порог](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpZ0C.png).

Comment: @alexolut, не уже, а ещё. [Просто тестирование короче программирования](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1295/178988), а тестировщики пришли первые))

Comment: @Qwertiy тут "уже" использовалось в смысле "другой".

Comment: @Qwertiy интересно, я думал, что ссылки на другие вопросы должны приводить к их появлению в блоке "Связанные". Но, видимо, на комментарии это не распространяется.

Comment: @alexolut, это баг: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2670/178988

Comment: @alexolut, \*LOL* - а вот ссылка из комментария выше сработала))

Comment: @Qwertiy сработала для связки, но название темы не развернулось. Либо дудочка, либо кувшинчик!

Comment: А почему нет метки объектно-ориентированное-программирование?

Comment: Ухахахаха. Э... Да, хороший вопрос. Есть ООП. Но ФП, по-моему, уже совсем безлико.

Comment: Обходимся [tag:ооп]

Comment: `функциональщина`

Comment: @rjhdby было уже, см. второй коммент.

Comment: сокращать: [функциональное-программ-ние]

Comment: @Соколов не вариант.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Определиться наконец-то с длиной метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5654/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @Arhad, тот вопрос задан как продолжение этого вопроса. Вообще не понятно зачем пытаться закрыть, если и тот и этот вопросы имеют статусы "завершено".

Comment: @Arhad текущий вопрос о длине метки на основном сайте. Другой - о различиях м/у Метой и основным. К тому же нужно ещё поправить страницу справки.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Длина метки [фактически теперь увеличена](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39808205#39808205) до 35 символов. Навесил уже новоиспечённую метку [функциональное-программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) на пару вопросов.