# Определиться наконец-то с длиной метки

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, справка

[Недавно выяснилось](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5546/176217), что предельная длина метки на ruSO - 30 символов. При этом на ruSO.meta всё ещё 25:

> [image: мета-25]

Предлагаю всё-таки задать ей какое-то единое число (заодно и [функциональное-программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) удовлетворить), иначе это будет продолжать не стыковаться со значением в описании привилегии [Создавать новые метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> - быть короче 25 символов;

Comment: [tag:функциональщина] должна и так влезть :-)

Comment: @Grundy или [tag:фу-программирование]

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [tag:фуграммирование] тогда уж сразу. Ещё можно в пару ему [tag:барграммирование].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Буквально сегодня максимальная длина метки [была увеличена](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490) до 35. [Проверил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/5654/revisions) — у нас тоже работает.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо всё же грядет deSO!

Comment: Фигня какая-то, [tag:функциональное-программирование] всё равно не создать. Ограничение 30 символов.

Comment: @alexolut ха, похоже что у нас на основном сайте есть собственное ограничение.

Comment: У нас все ограничения собственные! Короче, 25 превратилось в 35 на Мете, а на основном как было 30, так и осталось. Снимайте статус!

Comment: [попросил](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#comment973545_299490) чтоб пофиксили нам.