# Давайте всегда основной меткой делать более развёрнутую

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, синонимы-меток

Недавние обсудения синонимов

- [Объединить метки aws и amazon-web-services](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7009/220571)
- [Объединить метки Visual Studio Code](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7005/220571)

базировались на схожих проблемах.

Аргумент за более краткую: могут начинаться более длинные синонимы вроде [aws-cloudfront](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudfront), [aws-s3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-s3), [vscode-extensions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-extensions), [vscode-settings](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-settings) и т.д. На момент написания ни один из подобного рода синонимом у нас не существует.

Аргументом за является что по более полному названию лучше понятно, о чём эта метка. И я не вижу причины сильно экономить буквы. Если надо, то добавим более простую аббривеатуру как синоним.

Также иногда из-за недостаточно развёрнутых названий меток в будущем очень легко появляются неоднозначности.

Comment: Давайте начнём с [tag:sql-server], сделаем её синонимом к основной [tag:microsoft-structured-query-language-server].

Answer (score 5):

Обычно да, синонимизировать к более развернутой - хорошая идея, но это не всегда так. К примеру, если кто-то создаст метку [structured-query-language](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/structured-query-language), будем синонимизировать к ней [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)? Понятно, что это надуманный пример, но если взять из уже существующего:

[windows-form-application](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-form-application) является синонимом более краткой [winforms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms)

[android-development](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-development) является синонимом более краткой [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)

Так что не нужно устанавливать правило, что всегда выбирается развернутая. Для каждого случая нужно выбирать по ситуации.

Comment: В чем принципиальное отличие от ответа `Suvitruf`?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Видимо, ни в чем. Просто более подробно.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Всё-таки этот ответ содержит хорошую и развёрнутую аргументацию. А вот [ответ Suvitruf](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7039/220571) выглядит  безликим из-за отсутствия конкретных примеров.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov согласен, я на всякий случай уточнял

Answer (score 2):

А давайте смотреть на конкретную метку и уже потом решать, делать основной краткую или полную версию?

Answer (score 1):

А давайте.

Я с неделю поглядывал за обоими темами, смотрел какие аргументы будут за те или иные варианты. В обоих случаях перевес за метки без сокращений (если не уткнуться в ограничение на длину метки - это совершенно иная проблема, с которой [можно столкнуться](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5654/213987)).

Дополнительно, если нужны будут отдельные метки для подразделов типа [vscode-extensions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-extensions), [vscode-settings](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-settings) или [aws-cloudfront](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudfront), [aws-s3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-s3) их всегда можно сделать.

Comment: Мне не нравится слово "всегда". Что, если кто-то создаст [structured-query-language] будем к ней синонимизировать [sql]? Выбор основной метки зависит от многих факторов.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Хороший вопрос вы подняли, лично я озадачен. Можно конечно аргументировать, что сложилась практика, по которой используется sql и мы не столкнёмся в будущем с подобными проблемами, но это лишь бегство от ответа. Я подумаю над вашим вопросом. Мне кажется, что вам стоило это написать в поле ответ: уверен, что немало человек плюсанет (и я в том числе)

Comment: Отлично, давайте на единичных примерах сделаем правило.