# Криво показывается ссылка "Править" при длинном названии метки

Tags: дефект, метки, дизайн

Если название метки длинное, то ссылка "Править" показывается криво:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такие ситуации, скорее всего, мы не можем поправить локально. Поэтому надо искать подобные готовые баги на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Если их нет, то искать подтверждение поведения на других сайтах и по итогам постить новый баг на MSE. Самый простой способ подтверждения - поправить в html странице имя метки, учитывая, что текущий лимит соотвествует 35 символам.

Comment: Кстати, о метке на скриншоте есть [пост](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5546/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я [написал](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389379) об этом на MSE, посмотрим, что будет.